# How can i create a manual VSTS release to NuGet?

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Possible related, but seems outdated: [VSTS Release Task - Push to Nuget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298894/vsts-release-task-push-to-nuget)

I have a open-source project on GitHub, which is setup to do a build on VSTS.

Now, i would like to have a VSTS *Release* definition, which publishes my package to NuGet. I would like to do this manually..so don't want it part of my VSTS build.

Can someone point me to the best resource on how to do this?

Here's my Release Definition:
[image]

and pertinent part of logs:

```
2018-03-26T03:05:29.4416011Z Downloading artifacts from: https://rpm1984.visualstudio.com//_apis/resources/Containers/1753137?itemPath=drop&isShallow=true&api-version=4.1-preview.4
2018-03-26T03:05:29.6204337Z Downloading drop/RedditSentimentAnalyzer.1.0.0-CI-20180322-025919.nupkg to D:\a\r1\a\Master CI\drop\RedditSentimentAnalyzer.1.0.0-CI-20180322-025919.nupkg
2018-03-26T03:05:29.6248792Z Downloaded drop/RedditSentimentAnalyzer.1.0.0-CI-20180322-025919.nupkg to D:\a\r1\a\Master CI\drop\RedditSentimentAnalyzer.1.0.0-CI-20180322-025919.nupkg
2018-03-26T03:05:30.4524266Z Total Files: 1, Processed: 1, Skipped: 0, Failed: 0, Download time: 1.007 secs, Download size: 10227Bytes
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5070857Z Successfully downloaded artifacts to D:\a\r1\a/Master CI
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5101258Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - Master CI

 ...

2018-03-26T03:05:30.5119489Z ##[section]Starting: Use NuGet 4.3.0
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5122745Z ==============================================================================
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5122980Z Task         : NuGet Tool Installer
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5123255Z Description  : Acquires a specific version of NuGet from the internet or the tools cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this step to change the version of NuGet used in the NuGet steps.
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5123505Z Version      : 0.1.5
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5123696Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5123904Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=852538)
2018-03-26T03:05:30.5124656Z ==============================================================================
2018-03-26T03:05:31.7510971Z Downloading: https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.3.0/nuget.exe
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8479515Z Caching tool: NuGet 4.3.0 x64
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8600552Z Using version: 4.3.0
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8602827Z Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.3.0 x64
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8603258Z Using tool path: D:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8605921Z Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: D:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8723553Z ##[section]Finishing: Use NuGet 4.3.0

...

123456789101112
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8764514Z ##[section]Starting: Push artifact to NuGet2018-03-26T03:05:31.8770703Z ==============================================================================2018-03-26T03:05:31.8770932Z Task         : NuGet2018-03-26T03:05:31.8771244Z Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.2018-03-26T03:05:31.8771593Z Version      : 2.0.242018-03-26T03:05:31.8771774Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation2018-03-26T03:05:31.8772001Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)2018-03-26T03:05:31.8772231Z ==============================================================================2018-03-26T03:05:33.2855694Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 650012018-03-26T03:05:33.3914203Z Active code page: 650012018-03-26T03:05:33.4169477Z ##[section]Finishing: Push artifact to NuGet 

2018-03-26T03:05:31.8764514Z ##[section]Starting: Push artifact to NuGet
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8770703Z ==============================================================================
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8770932Z Task         : NuGet
2018-03-26T03:05:31.8771244Z Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard a

Find
No Results
```

```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nuget task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget#push-nuget-packages) and choose `push` command:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I set this up.. created a NuGet.org service endpoint with my account/api key, created the release, everything looks okay and release was 'deployed' (after i hit deploy). But.. nothing is on NuGet under my packages. Can you check on your end to see what im missing? my VSTS namespace is: rpm1984.visualstudio.com

Comment: If you publish the package manually with command line (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/publish-a-package), are you able to publish it successfully? Could you share your log? Also, as push packages to nuget.org you must use nuget.exe v4.1.0 or above, try to add [NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/tool/nuget?view=vsts) before Nuget task.

Comment: Hi Cece - yes, it worked fine with command line. I tried adding the NuGet tool installer task too, still same result. Interestingly the logs for the Nuget push task shows it still might be using "2.0.24". Do i need to force it to use the latest? Updating question with more info..

Comment: Is your Nuget package under path `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg`? Please check it.

Comment: sorry for the delay on this. Yep, it seems to be there. The logs seem good too. Can i send the VSTS logs to you to check out? Can you provide an email?